# JPA Query MONTH/YEAR functions

Tags: java, orm, jpa, jpql

How can I write a JPA query using `MONTH` function just like sql query?

```
@NamedQuery(name="querybymonth", query="select t from table1 t where MONTH(c_Date) = 5")
```

When I use the above pattern for query, I get an error: `unexpected token - MONTH`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you are using EclipseLink (2.1) you can use the FUNC() function to call any database function that is not defined in the JPA JPQL spec.

i.e.
FUNC('MONTH', c_Date)

In JPA 2.1 (EclipseLink 2.5) the [FUNCTION](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Release/2.5/JPA21#JPQL_function) syntax becomes part of the specification (and replaces the EclipseLink-specific FUNC).

If you are using TopLink Essentials, you cannot do this in JPQL, but you can define a TopLink Expression query for it (similar to JPA 2.0 criteria), or use native SQL.

Also if you are using any JPA 2.0 provider and using a Criteria query there is a function() API that can be used to define this.

Comment: Hi James, Thanks for your answer. I am actually using toplink essentials. I applied the way as above bu still I get:

Unexpected Token - FUNC.

Please Help!

Comment: @venomrld As James wrote, this FUNC stuff is available EclipseLink 2.1+, see [Bug 300512](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=300512). So don't expect to find it in TopLink Essentials.

Comment: So I'm stuck. Please help if some way exists. I'm using netbeans 6.5 and visual faces for development. Seems I've to change pretty much code to migrate.

Answer (score 7):

I want to query YEAR(itemDate) but the function doesn't exit, then i saw the SUBSTRING() function so what i did was
`Select q from table where SUBSTRING(itemDate, 1, 4)='2011'`
and it works for me! hope it helps!

if you need you a dynamic variable, you can do that too. here :poDate is the year which is deifned in the setParameter();

```
@NamedQuery(name = "PurchaseOrders.findByYear", query = "SELECT p FROM PurchaseOrders p WHERE SUBSTRING(p.poDate, 1, 4) = :poDate")

Query q = em.createNamedQuery("PurchaseOrders.findByYear");
q.setParameter("poDate", s_year+"");
```

but if your okay with your solutions, that'll be fine. i just find JPA faster to execute.

Comment: Thanks for reply..
Actually the problem I am facing that the values are dynamic.. i.e
The values are taken from variables only...
So I switched to native SQL queries and they work great.
Anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

The `MONTH()` function exists in Hibernate HQL but is not a standard JPA function. Maybe your JPA provider has some proprietary equivalent but you didn't mention it. If it doesn't, fall back on native SQL.

---

> I am using Toplink Essentials for the same. Please help, if any function exists in Toplink. Thanks.

To my knowledge, TopLink doesn't have a direct equivalent. So either use a native SQL query or maybe a TopLink Expression query (not sure about this, and not sure this is available in TopLink Essentials).

Comment: Hi! I am using Toplink Essentials for the same. Please help, if any function exists in Toplink. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me with hibernate (4.3.9.Final) & JPA 2.1.

@NamedQuery(name = "PartyEntity.findByAID", query = "select distinct psc.party from PartyShortCode psc where (psc.shortCode = :aidNumber or **FUNCTION('REPLACE',psc.accountReference,' ','')** = :aidNumber) and psc.sourceSystem in :sourceSystem")

Answer (score -1):

if your class holds a date type variable, you can use a query like this:

```
@Query("select m from Movement m where m.id_movement_type.id=1 and SubString(cast(m.date as text),1,4) = :year")
    List<Movement> buysForYear(@Param("year") String year);
```