# How to use to_char with JPA for dates

Tags: oracle, jpa

I want to create a query with JPA using dates. I´ve created this query with Oracle

```
 "SELECT * FROM PMAR_PRON WHERE to_char(PRO_DATE,'mm')=10 and 
to_char(PRO_DATE,'YYYY') = 2015;"
```

it works well but i don´t know 
     how to convert it at JPA.

```
SELECT * FROM PMAR_PRON WHERE to_char(PRO_DATE,'mm')=10 and 
to_char(PRO_DATE,'YYYY') = 2015;"
```

I want to get records of month 10 and year 2015.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674567/jpa-query-month-year-functions) for some options.  JPA does not have particularly good native date function support.  The main reason for this is that date implementation on various databases can be so different.

Comment: I tried but did not work. says that function MONTH is invalid

Comment: Thank you to everyone. I solved it using NativeQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
TypedQuery<MyObject>  query = em.createQuery("SELECT    * FROM PMAR_PRON WHERE to_char(PRO_DATE,'mm')=10 and to_char(PRO_DATE,'YYYY') =  :yr", MyObject.class);

query.setParameter("vr",year);
return query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In addition to the answer you've provided, please consider providing a brief explanation of why and how this fixes the issue.

Comment: a simple "to_char" does not work with JPA. i tried OPERATOR('ToChar', PRO_DATE,'YYYY') but did not get results,

Comment: Thank you to everyone. I solved it using NativeQuery