# JPA Query for MONTH in gregorian calendar

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

How do I query for `MONTH`

This is what I have

```
select o from Order o where func('month', o.date) = :date
```

But then I get

```
ORA-00904: "MONTH": invalid identifier
```

Already tried several things put can't find a solution

Comment: Can you show us at least one of these `several things` you tried?

Comment: `where month(o.date)` `where extract(month, o.date)` for example

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674567/jpa-query-month-year-functions).

Comment: I saw that one but I keep getting `invalid identifier`

Comment: Since you got an oracle error message: in Oracle you could get the month like this: to_char(date, 'mm'). Maybe you try func('to_char', o.date, 'mm).

Comment: Thanks that worked.